# Override DBAL Type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/working-with-datetime.html

I tried to use this code to make an UTC DateTime type. However, the code is not being called.

What confuses me is this section:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType;

Type::overrideType('datetime', UTCDateTimeType::class);
Type::overrideType('datetimetz', UTCDateTimeType::class);
```

There is no explanation where this code should be called. It only says "before bootstrapping the ORM", which after hours of googling I still haven't figured out what that means and I'm at a dead end now.

I tried to put the code in the same file as the UTCDateTimeType class, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With symfony, new doctrine types shall be declared in the `config/doctrine.yaml` file.

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            datetime:   DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType
            datetimez:  DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType
```

Be sure that the class `DoctrineExtensions\DBAL\Types\UTCDateTimeType` exists.

Here is a full example to install a spatial extension and declare the [geometric types](https://lo-doctrine-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#declare-your-geometric-types).